# add multiple lines to multiple files in a directory using ansible

Tags: ansible, insertafter

I would like to add some lines to multiple .conf files in a directory e.g. `/etc/abc/xabc/`.

The two lines I would like to add are below:

```
Composite=1
Extension=1
```

I would like these lines to appear after the line containing `[protocol]`.

How can I do this?

I am not sure how to proceed on this one; see my attempt below - even though I know it's erroneous:

```
- name: add line

- lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ item }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
    insertafter: [Protocol]
  with_items: xxxxxx
```

I assume I have to also register the output of the (`/etc/abc/xabc/`) directory?

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like you want to edit ini files, so the [`ini_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ini_file_module.html) module is much more appropriate:

```
- ini_file:
    dest: /path/to/destination/file.ini
    section: Protocol
    option: "{{ item.option }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
    - { option: Composite, value: 1 }
    - { option: Extension, value: 1 }
```

Second, it looks like you want to use a nested loop. For clarity, I would go with including a file in an outer loop over the fileglob of the destination directory and doing the configuration in the included file. For example, the `inner_loop.yml`:

```
- ini_file:
    dest: "{{ destination_file }}"
    section: Protocol
    option: "{{ item.option }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
    - { option: Composite, value: 1 }
    - { option: Extension, value: 1 }
```

and outer:

```
- include: inner_loop.yml
  with_fileglob:
    - /etc/abc/xabc/*
  loop_control:
    loop_var: destination_file
```

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/768425/197039) suggests another possible solution for combining loop over items with loop over glob.